# Swift Core Data : enums in Core Data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, enums

I am trying to implement a core data model which effectively mirrors a view model I use when extracting info from a specific API. I have most of it sorted but am struggling with one attribute.  The attribute in question is:

```
enum UnitType: String, Codable {
    case psi
    case kPa
    case litre
    case usg = "gallon"
    case kmph = "km/hour"
    case mph = "miles/hour"
    case celsius
    case fahrenheit
    case kgpmcubed = "kgpercubicmeter"
    case lbspusg = "lbsperusg"
    case lbspftcubed = "lbspercubicfeet"
    case apidensity
    case kg = "kilogram"
    case lbs = "pound"
}
```

I need to be able to set an enum value here as the view controller uses this UnitType property for various calculations based on this enum. How can I create an enum using core data? Essentially I need to be able to set this value like this:

```
MyEntity.unitType = viewModel.UnitType
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't store the `enum` type as such in `CoreData`, but you can store it's `rawValue`. Since your enum has a rawValue of `String` type you can store it's rawValue and convert back to `enum` by using the enum's `init` method, like this:

```swift
coreDataModel.unitType = viewModel.unitType.rawValue
```

and:

```swift
viewModel.unitType = UnitType(rawValue: coreDataModel.unitType)
```

Note: When converting from `rawValue` to `enum` type it would be optional because the `String` could be anything and could not match with any of the `case` provided in the `enum`. Hence, it would be required to provide a `default` value.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't save enums in `CoreData`.

You can have a `String` variable in your model:

```
class MyEntity: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var unitType: String
}
```

And then you can convert it to your UnitType on the go.

```
myEntity.unitType = viewModel.UnitType.rawValue

viewModel.unitType = UnitType(rawValue: myEntity.unitType)!
```